# MNIST - tf.estimator.DNNClassifier

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I'm trying to use `DNNClassifier` to solve the MNIST with one-hot coding output.

However, the error occurs

> "ValueError: Mismatched label shape. Classifier configured with n_classes=1.  Received 10. Suggested Fix: check your `n_classes` argument to the estimator and/or the shape of your label."

I know similar question may have been asked before but is there any new way that I could solve this out if i really want the one-hot coding output with `DNNClassifier`? thanks

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import mnist
# the data is split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

#convert the single output label to 10 output label
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)
    classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=[tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[28, 28])],
    hidden_units=[10],
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001),
    n_classes=10,
)

# Define the training inputs
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": x_train},
    y=y_train,
    num_epochs=None,
    batch_size=50,
    shuffle=True,
)

classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=100000)

# Define the test inputs
test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": x_test},
    y=y_test,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False
)

# Evaluate accuracy
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn)["accuracy"]
print("\nTest Accuracy: {0:f}%\n".format(accuracy_score*100))
```

Comment: Provide complete error message

Comment: On which line you are getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code (in `numpy_input_fn` function call)

```
y=y_train.astype(np.int32),
```

instead of

```
y=y_train,
```

Also comment out `to_categorical` call.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i know one_hot coding output is the reason why the error occurs, however, i would like to have it as the output, "y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)" was trying to transform the single output into the 10 column one_hot coding output.

Comment: This function is designed in such a way to accept the class numbers rather than 1-hot encodings. Why do you need it specifically in 1-hot encoding?